# Selecting specific query for offset

Tags: functions, query

I'm trying to offset the first 3 posts in the **functions.php** from a query but the next affects all my queries in the homepage:

```
 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'myprefix_query_offset', 1 );
 function myprefix_query_offset(&$the_query) {

    //Before anything else, make sure this is the right query...
    if ( ! $the_query->is_home() ) {
        return;
    }

    //First, define your desired offset...
    $offset = 3;

    //Next, determine how many posts per page you want (we'll use WordPress's settings)
    $ppp = get_option('posts_per_page');

    //Next, detect and handle pagination...
    if ( $the_query->is_paged ) {

        //Manually determine page query offset (offset + current page (minus one) x posts per page)
        $page_offset = $offset + ( ($the_query->query_vars['paged']-1) * $ppp );

        //Apply adjust page offset
        $the_query->set('offset', $page_offset );

    }
    else {

        //This is the first page. Just use the offset...
        $the_query->set('offset',$offset);

    }
}
```

Is there any way to simply call one specific query?

Thank you.

Comment: Share the rest of the code so viewers have some context.

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot

Comment: Where do you want the query to have the offset? Is it with some posts with another post type? Your if at the start only checks, if it is the home page of your website. If not, the query is adjusted. You will have to define your constraints.